# Handle multiple operations inside a single jQuery method when we press Enterkey from a textbox

Tags: php, html, jquery, validation, enter

I want to handle two operations when I click the enter key after entering text in one textbox.
Two operations are

1. Move the cursor to the next textbox
2. Establish a serial communication using php code

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:text:first').focus();
  var $inp = $('input:text');
  $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    //var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) { // Enter key is pressed
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behaviour of enter key
      var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
      $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
      // Ajax query to send request to php
      var test = $("#command-text").val();
      var inputtext = test;
      var command = "1";
      // var mode = $(".common-input mb-20").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller.php",
        data: {
          inputtext: inputtext,
          command: command
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          var feedback = "@" + $("#command-text").val() + "#";
          $("#feedback").val(feedback);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When I tried out with the following code,only one operation is executing,either cursor will move to the next textbox or establish communication.
Kindly help me to solve this issue
Code I tried is as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax your position of brackets is not correct try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:text:first').focus();
  var $inp = $('input:text');
  $inp.bind('keydown', function(e) {
    //var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) { // Enter key is pressed
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behaviour of enter key
      var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
      $(":input:text:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
      // Ajax query to send request to php
      var test = $("#command-text").val();
      var inputtext = test;
      var command = "1";
      // var mode = $(".common-input mb-20").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller.php",
        data: {
          inputtext: inputtext,
          command: command
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          var feedback = "@" + $("#command-text").val() + "#";
          $("#feedback").val(feedback);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried by correcting the syntax,but still serial communication to a port using php is not establishing.

Comment: do you want to execute when document is ready as  you have written inside $(function () { })

Comment: I need to execute both operations when we press enter key after entering text in.the input textbox.

Comment: The issue got fixed by rewriting the code to execute when document is ready and by changing the binding event to keyup event.Thank you for your great support.